# find element by xpath 'No such element' error

Tags: xpath

Can someone tell me why im not able to access the "select" xpath? I'm getting "No such element exist" error. The website link is: https://www2.fdic.gov/sdi/main3.asp?cert=26486&repdte=MostCurrent. I'm using selenium webdriver.

```
select=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/select')
```

Comment: because that url uses frames...? the content is not actually AT that url. it's in subdocuments housed within frames.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select=driver.findElement(By.xpath('//form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/select'))
```

In the beginning of xpath you use '//' and not need 'html/body'

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Marc B above. **The select element is inside a frame, hence unless you switch to the frame, your code won't work.**

**1-** First, **Switch to frame** using the below code (multiple ways are there, this is one of them):

```
   driver.switch_to_frame("content") //Found that the select tag is under frame with name "content"
```

**2-** Then, use your code or the code below for the **select element**:

```
select=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@name='selColumnType2']')
```

**3-** After your task with the frame is over, use the below code to **switch back to main window** and proceed further:

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```